# Is there a way to write a script for Drupal without write a module?

Tags: php, drupal-6, drush

I want to retrieve field values of some nodes in Drupal 6.
Can I do this without writing a module as it is a small thing.
Can I do it using Drush,how to write a drush script for that?

Please anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your function in template.php file as you don't want to create a new module. But it is not recommended. It is better to have a common module for the whole project for this kind of functions.

Comment: can I do it by Drush script?As a small thing I was advisable for not to write a module.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "php-eval" drush argument, abbrevated with "eval":

```
drush @mysite eval '$nid = 12; $node = node_load($nid); var_export($node, TRUE);'
```

I wrote this script explicit, here is the shortened version:

```
drush @mysite eval 'var_export(node_load(12), TRUE));'
```

Running this command you get to know the structure of the node object.
If you know the field name, then run it like this:

```
drush @mysite eval 'var_export(node_load(12)->field_body, TRUE));'
```

The essence is: Take `drush eval` and run `node_load()` to get the node object.

Comment: Can I run it in the drush command prompt without writing a code inside the module?

Comment: Yes, all the above code is run at the shell prompt (and thus in the "drush prompt"). No Drupal code modification is needed.